# Data Selection in Adobe Flash Builder (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

Inside of Adobe Flash Builder, I am trying to bind data to a `comboBox`. Here is my scenario:

1. I have data services provided by `ColdFusion` which connects to a `MySQL` database.
2. I have connected the data services and they show in the inspector window as follows: `NameService`.
3. Inside `NameService` I have the following data types under `Tbl_names`(the name of the table in my `MySQL` database) `admin:String`, `dept:String`, `ID:Number`, `manager:String`, `name:String`, `pin:String`, and `store:String`.

With all of this being said, I have a `comboBox` with the ID of `nameBox`. I want to have `nameBox` only show the names of people who's `store:String` is equal to "Toyota". I can't figure this out for the life of me. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set the CFQUERY to limit your selection:

http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_database_queries.cfm

Comment: You are the master of rabbits ethrbunny. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I guess I should have asked before I marked it as answered :(. Would I place something like this directly into Flash Builder into one of my functions?

`<cfquery datasource="Entertainment">
  select *
  from Movies
</cfquery>`

Comment: http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2007/10/16/How-do-you-use-a-CF-Query-in-Flex

Comment: Much appreciated. Here is your answer back :)